# Google CDN Jquery load not working

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, google-cdn

I currently have an ugly array of separate javascript files in one of my layouts and I'm trying to clean it up using the Google CDN.

Current state (horrible I know):

```
...css...  
<%= yield :head %>

<%= javascript_include_tag "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.3/jquery.min.js" %>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.jquerytools.org/1.2.5/all/jquery.tools.min.js"></script>
<%= javascript_include_tag "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.13/jquery-ui.min.js" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "ui/jquery.ui.core", "ui/jquery.effects.core",
   "ui/jquery.effects.highlight", "ui/jquery.ui.widget", "ui/jquery.ui.tabs",
   "ui/jquery.ui.progressbar" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "jquery.ui.stars.min", "application", "rails" %>
```

I tried replacing the 2nd from bottom tag (with the long list of files) with:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.13/jquery-ui.min.js" %>
```

I am getting no luck with that - it seems as if the google file is not there at all (I checked my page source and it is loaded). What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know how to translate it into RAILS but this simple HTML should do the trick.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    if(typeof jQuery == 'undefined') {
        //<![CDATA[
        document.write("<script src='/includes/jquery-1.4.2.min.js' type='text/javascript'><\/script>");
        //]]>
    }
</script>
```

This would assume that your jQuery file is stored on `/includes/jquery-1.4.2.min.js`.
On Google's CDN failure, local copy will get fetched.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I noted that the Google Jquery-UI file is being fetched, but for some reason my document is acting as if it's not there. Things like UI-tabs, UI-progressbar, etc are behaving like they're lost.

Comment: @sscirrus best thing you can do is run your app with all the files on local system. Then, slowly pass them to CDN. Start with the jQuery main, then move to UI and then to the plugins and see how that works out for you. You'll probably catch the `bug` in the process...

Comment: One small comment, instead of specifying the protocol part... start with the "//ajax.googleapis.com/..." that way the same protocol as the page is used (http/https).

Comment: @Tracker1 that makes perfect sense but pop's a question, on a page that has mixed https/http content, if you load js with https and cache the resource wouldn't it make the whole thing faster as you would not have to download that resource twice (one for http and another for https)?

Comment: @Frankie the protocol should match the current page's protocol.. and you shouldn't mix content between http/https.

Comment: @Tracker1 after some careful thinking and reading absolutely agree with you.

Answer (score 3):

Sorry to dredge up an old post, but I'm not sure the question was actually answered.

I had a similar problem as you did, and the solution was actually quite simple: I was not including the CSS.  You can do so through Google's CDN as well:

```
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

or

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css' %>
```

Obviously this is for the ui-lightness theme; there are other themes available on the CDN (though not all of them).  I'm sure you can find those with a quick Google search.